# finding a closer value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to find a number that is more closer to a particular number. In current example that partitucal number is 15. I will pass n to method and it will return me the closest completely divided by 15
I want a method like this

```
function getCloser(no){
    if(no is closer to 0)    // in this case no can be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
        return 0
    if(no is closer to 15)   // in this case no can be 8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16...22
        return 15
    if(no is closer to 30)   // in this case no can be 23 to 37
        return 30
    and so on...

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function getCloser(a, b) {
    b = b || 15;
    return Math.round(a / b) * b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can do it with this ( untested ) function:

```
function getCloser(n)
   {
       return 15*(Math.round(n/15))
   }
```

This divides by fifteen and rounds up/down so for 7 it is 7/15 rounded to 0 -> 0 but for 8 rounded to 1, this multiplied by fifteen gives the closer number.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getCloser(no){
    return  Math.round(no/gap) * gap ;  
}


var gap = 15;
var str = getCloser(9) + "--" + getCloser(5) + "--" + getCloser(24) ;
alert(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eRCjd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly simple:

```
function getCloser (n, o) { 
    return (Math.round(n/o) * o);
}
```

see here for example http://jsfiddle.net/bnPHL/